# Fragment shader will overwrite the fragment color generated from rasterization?

Tags: opengl, graphics, fragment-shader, rasterizing

According to my understanding, the fragment shader takes the result from rasterization. However, according to Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice (3rd Edition), the rasterization will calculate the fragment color based on lighting in various directions:

```
for each pixel position (x, y):
closest[x, y] = ∞
for each triangle T:
   for each pixel position (x, y):
   let R be the ray through (x, y) from the eye
   let P be the intersection of R and T
   if P exists:
      sum = 0
      for each direction:
          sum += . . .
          if the distance to P is less than closest[x, y]:
             pixel[x, y] = sum
             closest[x, y] = |P − O|
```

so the fragment color pixel[x, y] is calculated base on lightings in the scene. So, after this, the fragment shader will apply colors, textures etc. to each fragement. How the colors in fragment shader or from the texture mix with the color calculated from rasterization?

Answer (score 1):

Fragment shader is your implementation of rasterization process, rasterization described is done by shader in fixed pipeline, flexible pipeline uses shader program you've supplied instead.

From opengl docs:
A Fragment Shader is the Shader stage that will processes a Fragment generated by theRasterization into a set of colors and a single depth value.

The fragment shader is the OpenGL pipeline stage after a primitive is rasterized. For each sample of the pixels covered by a primitive, a "fragment" is generated. Each fragment has aWindow Space position, a few other values, and it contains all of the interpolated per-vertex output values from the last Vertex Processing stage.

The output of a fragment shader is a depth value, a possible stencil value (unmodified by the fragment shader), and zero or more color values to be potentially written to the buffers in the current framebuffers.

If fragment shader is not supplied color of pixels in fragment will stay unmodified

Comment: "The output of a fragment shader is a depth value". To my understanding the depth value is calculated during rasterization.

Comment: Fragment shader is your implementation of rasterization process? I think fragment shader comes after rasterization in the pipeline.

Comment: @lightrek: That is not entirely accurate. It is possible to compute the depth during rasterization, but the fragment shader has final say. If a fragment shader never writes a depth, then the rasterized value can be used and hardware is designed to do an early depth-test and skip shading for any fragment that fails in this scenario. But if the fragment shader writes anything to `gl_FragDepth`, then the depth test must be performed after shading. The stencil test can also be done early for the same reason; there's a whole class of "early fragment tests."

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman: But the depth buffer generated during rasterization, right?

Comment: Again, that depends on whether the fragment shader writes a value to `gl_FragDepth` or not. If a shader writes its own value, no depth can be written until after shading (because the value generated by rasterization isn't the fragment's final depth). Generally it's best not to think about these optimizations and consider the depth buffer only being written to after shading.

Comment: @lightrek it comes AFTER step called "Rasterization" in terms of flexible pipeline.. if that guide OP referred to bases on fixed pipeline, then what fragment shader was doing was part of rasterization. Here might be some dubious info, because in different languages those steps called differently, e.g. in my native language dithering and rasterization are same word :P

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman didn't they ditched those predefined variables now? I lost track before 3.0 GLSL

Comment: @Swift: No, since dual depth rendering isn't really a meaningful thing `gl_FragDepth` is still very much the one and only place you can write depth values :) They got rid of `gl_FragData [...]` though, in favor of declaring your own color outputs and then hooking those up to color attachment locations in the FBO.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, shading happens after rasterization.

It is the programmable step in-between rasterization and output merging (blending). Rasterization interpolates (non-flat) per-vertex attributes and generates one or more samples per-fragment using the values it computed.

The values computed during rasterization are passed onto the fragment shader stage, which decides what to do with them (e.g. sample a texture at a specific coordinate) to produce color and depth. After shading, fragments that pass a depth/stencil test are merged (blended) with whatever already exists in the framebuffer according to the setup blend equation to produce a pixel.